# Simplest/Easiest way to print the current date from Scala REPL?

Tags: scala

Looking for a simple/easy way to get the current date in scala.

I can get this using:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
val now = LocalDate.now()
```

but I didn't know if there was a scala specific implementation that is preferred to the LocalDate one.

Comment: @jwvh, if you reformulate your comment as a question I can mark as correct and close out the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Scala Standard Library has no time/date classes. Scala code relies on Java libraries for that.

Answer (score 2):

*(Update 2023: Please just [use `java.time.*`](https://www.baeldung.com/current-date-time-and-timestamp-in-java-8) instead, the time package has been *very decent* since version 8)*

---

*(This is just for looking at current time from the console, in case you've found yourself so immersed into the Scala REPL that you don't know where else to get a clock)*

If you are on linux/unix, you can use the `:sh` command in the REPL together with the external `date` command:

```
scalaRepl> :sh date
res42: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ProcessResult = `date` (1 lines, exit 0)
```

The result is saved in the variable `res42`, and it is shown that the external process exited without errors (`0`), and printed one line.

You can get this line with

```
res42.lines
```

which will give you something like

```
res43: List[String] = List(Fri May 25 22:36:22 CEST 2018)
```

In [ammonite](http://ammonite.io/#Subprocesses), this would be just `%date`.